# How Can I Use jQuery .each Within A Function

Tags: jquery, each

I have a function that is running on all `<audio>` elements on a page.  It creates a new media player for each individual song.  That is working fine.  I am using WordPress so I'm pulling the song title and song artist from the database within the page template.  I am now trying to grab that info using jQuery and insert it into a `<div>` within the media player code.  I am getting the first song info for all three songs.  Here is the [page](http://kw.captchaintherye.com/portfolio/) with the outcome.

I have tried to use .each to iterate over the .song-title class which is what contains the song title and grab the title using .text but when I do that it grabs all three song titles and outputs for each song.

Each song is setup something like this in the template file:

```
<div class="song">
<div class="song-title d-none">Song Title</div>
<div class="song-artist d-none">Artist</div>
<audio preload="auto" src="song.mp3"></audio>
</div>
```

Javascript file has a function that runs on each `<audio>` tag and within that function is the following code:

```
//$('.song').each(function (index, value) {
   $songTitle = $('.song-title').html();
   $songArtist = $('.song-artist').html();
//});

$player.append('<div class = "song-info d-flex flex-column"><div class = "serif font-italic">' + $songTitle + '</div><div class = "small">' + $songArtist + '</div>');
```

Here is the [full code](http://kw.captchaintherye.com/wp-content/themes/wp-understrap/js/audio.js) if necessary.

I am trying to get each media player on the page to show the correct song title and artist.

Comment: `$songTitle = $('.song-title', value).html();` this will limit the scope of the search to the current `.song` element. You could also do this: `$songTitle = $(value).find('.song-title').html();`

Comment: @phuzi I did try to update per your comment and it was breaking the function meaning that the audio player didn't initiate giving me an empty black box.

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being the working solution.  In order to limit the scope I had to use `.siblings()` to traverse the DOM and isolate the variables for each song.

```
$songTitle = $this.siblings('.song-title').text();
$songArtist = $this.siblings('.song-title').text();

$player.append('<div class="song-info d-flex flex-column"><div class="serif font-italic">' + $songTitle + '</div><div class="small">' + $songArtist + '</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to restrict the scope of the selectors when getting song title and artist.

```
$('.song').each(function (index, value) {
    $songTitle = $('.song-title', value).text();
    $songArtist = $('.song-artist', value).text();

    $player.append('<div class="song-info d-flex flex-column"><div class="serif font-italic">' + $songTitle + '</div><div class="small">' + $songArtist + '</div>');
});
```

Comment: I tried this but am now getting all three song tiles showing up in the song info ```div```.

Comment: So essentially it's appending three times

Comment: @MikeOberdick Can you add a [mcve], it would appear that the situation is more complicated than your question presents.